# Python: Hide member of base class in derived class

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, member-hiding

How to override a member of base class in my derived class so that accesses to such member cause invoking the derived member?
Consider folllowing example? `__tmp` is overwritten in `B` and should be return in case of a call to `tmp()`

```
class A:
    __tmp = {"A" : 1,
             "B" : 2}
    def tmp(self):
        return self.__tmp

class B(A):
    __tmp = {"A" : 10,
             "B" : 20}
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

b = B()
print(b.tmp()) # Expect to print {'A': 10, 'B': 20} here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use obfuscated variable names:

```
class A:
    _tmp = {"A" : 1,
             "B" : 2}
    def tmp(self):
        return self._tmp

class B(A):
    _tmp = {"A" : 10,
             "B" : 20}
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

b = B()
print(b.tmp()) # Works as expected
```

The problem was that `self.__tmp` is name-mangled behind the scenes by python and resolves to `self._A__tmp` since `tmp` is a method of the `A` class. You wanted `self._B__tmp`. If you had redefined the `tmp` method in `B` it would have worked, but that's a silly way of doing it, since it defeats one of the purposes of inheritance -- avoiding code duplication.

Reserve the use of `__private` variables for when you wish to *avoid* name clashes with the attributes of subclasses. In this case, you really wish to *achive* such a naming collition.

If you want to make an attribute private, it suffices with a single underscore, since [we're all consenting adults here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Objects).

Comment: Thank you, that works! What exactly do you mean with `obfuscated variable names`? The double-underscore or just `tmp` from this example?

Comment: The use of two leading underscores on an attribute causes it to be name-mangled. This is explained in detail in [pep-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (search for "leading underscore").

Answer (score 0):

From the description it isn't clear to my, why should be wanted and should make sense.
Looks like a rather strange design. But nevertheless, why don't you just overwrite the getter?

```
class A( object ):
    __tmp = {"A" : 1,
             "B" : 2}
    def tmp( self ):
        return self.__tmp

class B( A ):
    __tmp = {"A" : 10,
             "B" : 20}
    def __init__( self ):
        super( B, self ).__init__()

    def tmp( self ):
        return B.__tmp


b = B()
print( b.tmp() )  # Expect to print {'A': 10, 'B': 20} here
```

Comment: Implementing it both doesn't make sense. It's only unnecessary work. The goal of this design is to have a base class `A`, which provides some names (`__tmp`). Subclasses may define its own names or accept the base class's names. Nevertheless the access to this must return the right ones.